# Can anyone help me to solve this example of Blaschke Product, please?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone help me to solve this example, please?

Example of Blaschke Product:

Show that we cannot have a bounded analytic function on B(0,1) with its zeros being 
1/2,  2/3 , 3/4, 4/5 ,...
(hint: $b_n = n/(n+1)$).

Comment: What is a "boundary analytic function"? (If that term is standard, it has become so after I learned complex analysis.)

Comment: Hi Danial, according to some papers which I got from my supervisor. I will write about it as he did " suppose we have a bounded analytic function f not identically equals to 0 on B(0,1)"  I hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, so it's what's commonly known as (an element of) $H^\infty (\setminus\{0\})$.

Comment: Hint: there's a (necessary and sufficient) conditions on the zeros of an $f \in H^\infty\setminus\{0\}$. The name Nevanlinna might help finding it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but for me it is difficult to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a bounded (not identically zero) analytic function with zero sequence $(a_1, a_2, \ldots )$, then
$$\sum (1-|a_n|) < \infty$$
and conversely any sequence satisfying the above is the zero sequence of a bounded analytic function. This result is most likely in your textbook (the usual proof is via Jensen's formula). In your setting
$$\sum \left(1-\frac{n}{n+1}\right) = \sum \frac1{n+1}$$
diverges, so no such function exists.